# Subclassing an Akka Agent

Tags: scala, akka

I would like to create a subclass of `akka.agent.Agent`.  I have tried the following...

```
import akka.agent.Agent
import markets.tickers.Tick

class TickerAgent(val initialValue: Tick) extends Agent[Tick] {
  ???
}
```

...at which point I am prompted to implement the remaining methods of the abstract `Agent` class.  However, I want to keep the default implementations for these methods.  It seem from the [source](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-agent/src/main/scala/akka/agent/Agent.scala) that the default implementations are defined in a final, private `SecretAgent` class inside the `Agent` companion object.

Is there anyway for me to somehow import or otherwise access the default `Agent` when implementing a subclass of `Agent`?

Comment: Why do you want to subclass `Agent`?

Comment: @Ryan Is there an obvious reason why I shouldn't be trying to subclass Agent? Other than a general preference for composition over inheritance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge, there is no other way except implementing the abstract methods defined `Agent[T]` class. You can call the default methods inside your methods implementation.

Comment: Can you provide an example of calling the default methods inside my own implementation? I implemented all of the abstract methods and then called `super` appropriately however this didn't work.

Comment: I tried to use akka agents many times and I was confused about its usage and semantics, but anyway, I see that implementing a subclass of Agent[T] to the default value is not a straight forward. It needs to implement the abstract method by the way it was described above every method in the API Doc. For example, you should return the initialValue in the apply method, and change your initialValue to a new one in the send method and so on.

Comment: Basically I need to copy the implementations of all `Agent` methods in order to subclass `Agent`.  Seems like either really bad design choice or develop specifically did not want others to subclass `Agent`...